# How to calculate mean age for tenure position having a number of different positions and people holding them?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 4 variables: "position", "year start", "year finish", "year birth". I need to calculate a mean age for a person holding all position in a given year (sum of all ages in a given year over the number of ages, to be clear).

So, the final result must be like this:

| year | mean age |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 45 |
| 2001 | 43 |
| 2002 | 34 |

Here is the example of data:

| position | year_start | year_finish | year_birth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021 | 2024 | 1948 |
| A | 2013 | 2021 | 1945 |
| A | 2006 | 2012 | 1957 |
| A | 2002 | 2005 | 1956 |
| A | 1999 | 2001 | 1935 |
| B | 2007 | 2024 | 1959 |
| B | 2003 | 2006 | 1946 |
| C | 2016 | 2024 | 1955 |
| C | 2010 | 2015 | 1949 |
| C | 2007 | 2009 | 1952 |
| C | 2003 | 2006 | 1927 |

Comment: I pasted you question in ChatGPT and said I wanted an answer in R coding language, SHAZ-AM! Share the final solution as answer for others to benefit... (it's OK to answer your own questions here on [so]).

Comment: Thanks! But I tried a couple of hours and ChatGPT didn't help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a cleaner way to do it, but:

```
# Load libraries.

library(tidyverse)

# Load data.

df <- data.frame(
  position = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
  year_start = c(2021, 2013, 2006, 2002, 1999, 2007, 2003, 2016, 2010, 2007, 2003),
  year_finish = c(2024, 2021, 2012, 2005, 2001, 2024, 2006, 2024, 2015, 2009, 2006),
  year_birth = c(1948, 1945, 1957, 1956, 1935, 1959, 1946, 1955, 1949, 1952, 1927)
)

# Get list of years.

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(year_list = mapply(seq, year_start, year_finish))

# Calculate ages based on that list of years.

df3 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(y = map2(year_birth, year_list, function(x, y){
    y - x
    }))

# Generate mean age by year data.

df4 <- df3 %>% 
  select(year_list, y) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(year_list, y))

names(df4) <- c("year", "age")

mean_age_data <- df4 %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_age = mean(age))

mean_age_data
```

With output:

```
A tibble: 26 × 2
year    mean_age
<dbl>   <dbl>
1999    64.0
2000    65.0
2001    66.0
2002    46.0
2003    60.0
2004    61.0
2005    62.0
2006    62.7
2007    51.0
2008    52.0
2009    53.0
2010    55.0
2011    56.0
2012    57.0
2013    62.0
2014    63.0
2015    64.0
2016    63.0
2017    64.0
2018    65.0
2019    66.0
2020    67.0
2021    69.2
2022    68.0
2023    69.0
2024    70.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will test it tomorrow.

Comment: Brill. If it answers your question please mark the answer as correct / useful.

Comment: Thank you again! It seems to be working as I wanted. Marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

We could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(year = map2(year_start, year_finish, seq),
         id = row_number()) %>% 
  unnest(year) %>% 
  group_by(position, year_start) %>% 
  mutate(mean_age = mean(year - year_birth, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-id, -year) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
position year_start year_finish year_birth mean_age
   <chr>         <int>       <int>      <int>    <dbl>
 1 A              1999        2001       1935     65  
 2 A              2002        2005       1956     47.5
 3 A              2006        2012       1957     52  
 4 A              2013        2021       1945     72  
 5 A              2021        2024       1948     74.5
 6 B              2003        2006       1946     58.5
 7 B              2007        2024       1959     56.5
 8 C              2003        2006       1927     77.5
 9 C              2007        2009       1952     56  
10 C              2010        2015       1949     63.5
11 C              2016        2024       1955     65
```

Comment: My interpretation was that OP wants a mean age within each year, not within each row. In which case the solution would be similar, but grouping by `position` and `year` instead of `year_start`, then just `summarize()`.

Comment: Thank you!
But that's not exactly what I need. I need a column with years (1999,2000,2001 etc.) and the column with mean age across the positions in a given year (say, 64,34,71 etc.)

Comment: @zephryl. you are right. I somehow did not get it! I thought mean age by position and year_start.